# OSM getting ways and nodes of a relation instead of an area

Tags: openstreetmap

I am new with OSM queries, I understand that areas are not real entities but they work very well, let's suppose I call the following query:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
area["name"="Tenerife"]->.a;
(
 way(area.a)[amenity=parking];
 node(area.a)[amenity=hospital];
 rel(area.a)[admin_level=6]["is_in:country"="Spain"];
);
out geom;
```

So I thought that if I have a relation number instead of using an area would be faster and more specific, but how can I do that? because I have look for it many hours and I cannot get it work, I understand it must be something like:

```
  [out:json][timeout:25];
  rel(2108882)->.a;
   (
   way(XXXXX)[amenity=parking];
   node(XXXXX)[amenity=hospital];
  );
  out geom;
```

Any clue on what can make it work? How I set the filtering to use that relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a relation id, you can use the `map_to_area` statement to find the respective area, assuming it exists.

Your query would then look as follows:

`rel(2108882);map_to_area->.a;
(
 way(area.a)[amenity=parking];
 node(area.a)[amenity=hospital];
);
out geom;`

`map_to_area` simply adds a specific offset to the way/relation id you provided previously (see [documentation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Map_way.2Frelation_to_area_.28map_to_area.29)). In your example, `map_to_area` would turn relation 2108882 into area 3602108882 by adding the offset value of 3600000000 for relations.

This all has absolutely no performance implications.

The second approach you've outlined doesn't really work. At this time, you really need an existing area for this kind of query. Usually areas are created by a server-side script and you as a user cannot really influence this. Also, there's a 1:1 relationship between an area the its respective way or relation.

Read more about how areas are created [on the OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Areas).

Comment: Amazing, really love that query :). thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to mmd's answer, you can try:

```
[out:json];
(
 way(area:3602108882)[amenity=parking];
 node(area:3602108882)[amenity=hospital];
 rel(area:3602108882)[admin_level=6]["is_in:country"="Spain"];
);
out geom;
```

but it does not work faster than your first query. See also http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#By_area_.28area.29